# Embedding Unix date in a C program

Tags: c, unix

I have a C program running on a Unix box.

I would like to print a timestamp to an output file - at the moment I use the command `date` to print the datetime on the terminal.

```
fprintf(outputfile, "%s ", date);
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use POSIX [strftime(3) - format date and time](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) for a C solution.  It use the same format strings as `date(1)`

I also recommend you read the [standard library intro(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/intro).